# Css code for center navigation menu is not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

My css code is following:-

```
    #nav {
      position: relative;
      display: block;

      margin: 0;
      background: #333;
      z-index: 1;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      display: -webkit-box;
    }
#desktop-nav .nav-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms linear;

  transition: color 200ms linear;
}

#desktop-nav .nav-item:hover, #desktop-nav .nav-item:active {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

and html code is:--

```
<div id="nav">
               <nav id="desktop-nav">
            <a class="nav-item" href="#1">Github</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#2">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#3">Community</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#4">Docs</a>
        </nav>
```

Here,I use the below code for make center the navigation menu..

```
 -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      display: -webkit-box;
```

but it is working in google chrome..but not in firefox..I need cross browser compatiable code for mozilla????

Comment: replace "-webkit " with -moz for morzilla "-webkit" for chrome

Comment: so, I have to add  -webkit-box-align: center; and  -moz-box-align: center;???

Comment: ya you need to use  -moz for mozilla

Comment: I added   -moz-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;  display: -moz-box;...but in mozila still it is not working

Comment: can you show your html code ?

Comment: r u there make it fast i need to go ...... ?

Comment: I have edited the question..you can check

Comment: Now,I got it..thank you...

Comment: ok  you can also  use " float: left " instead of "float: right", after "float:left " you can easily assign "margin-left: ** ;"  - note replace ** with your adjustable margin  value .......

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it, you can either give your `div` the `text-align : center` CSS property, or put this for the `div`:

```
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
-moz-box-pack: center;
display: -webkit-box;`
```